# Control signal with two buttons

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am trying to make a VHDL code in Quartus that turns on buzzer when I push button1 on the demo board and turns it off when I push button 2. But, it doesn't react to button2. It compiles without errors, but doesn't work as I expected. It always produces sound.

How do I make it to turn on when I push button1 and turn off when I push button2?

```
architecture Behavioral of buzz is
signal Hz_counter : natural range 0 to 56818 := 0;
signal wave : std_logic := '0';
signal sound_on : std_logic := '0';
signal sound_off : std_logic := '0';
begin
process(clk, button1, button2)
begin
         if rising_edge(clk) then
            Hz_counter <= Hz_counter + 1;
            if Hz_counter >= 56818 then
                wave <= not wave;
                Hz_counter <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
          
          if rising_edge(button1) then
            sound_on <= '1';
          end if;       
          if rising_edge(button2) then
            sound_off <= '1';  
        end if;
          
          if (sound_on = '1') then
              sound_off <= '0';
          end if;
          if (sound_off = '1') then
              sound_on <= '0';
          end if; 
end process;

    buzzer <= wave when (sound_on = '1') else '0';
     
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Why do you need "sound_off"? Couldn't the rising edge of button1 set sound_on=1 and rising edge on button2 set sound_on=0?

Comment: @DarkFranX There are no real-world flip-flops with two or more independent clock inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have built two flip-flops that are set by the rising edges of buttons, but asynchronously reset by the set state of each other.

Initially, `sound_on` and `sound_off` are '0'.

If you press `button1`, `sound_on` becomes '1'. This keeps `sound_off` at '0' asynchronously:

```vhdl
        if (sound_on = '1') then
            sound_off <= '0';
        end if;
```

If you want to observe the same effect but for `button2`, press it as the first button. Now you are not able to switch the sound on with `button1`.

---

The solution is to avoid this kind of dead-lock. Use only one flip-flop to store "sound on/off".

The most simple alternative is to use `button1` to set and `button2` to reset:

```vhdl
        if button1 = '1' then
            sound_on <= '1';
        elsif button2 = '1' then
            sound_on <= '0';
        end if;
```

If you want a clocked flip-flop, use `button1` as clock to set and `button2` as reset. Since the asynchronous signal has higher priority in the real world, you need write this:

```vhdl
        if button2 = '1' then
            sound_on <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(button1) then
            sound_on <= '1';
        end if;
```

Finally, a pure synchronous design is:

```vhdl
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if button1 = '1' then
                sound_on <= '1';
            elsif button2 = '1' then
                sound_on <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
```